# Migrating an Azure Functions project to Durable Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Trying to convert my Azure Function project to use **Durable Azure Functions**. I added the **E1_HelloSequence** sample class to my project, but the durable function never shows up as one of the Http functions listed when the Azure function runtime starts locally. Any one able to provide some guidance ?

The DurableTaskExtension is initiated ... and the DurableFunction (HelloSequence) is listed ... but not listed as an Http Function:
[image]

Comment: This issue also happens if I create a new blank project, add the NuGet reference and the sample HelloSequence.cs to the project. HelloSequence is recognized as a function but also does not show up in the http functions ...

Answer (score 4):

That's because they are not HTTP functions, they are rather triggered by queue messages behind the scenes.

There are some webhooks on Durable Function extension level on top of that, which you can use: [HTTP APIs doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-http-api) describes that in more details.

Have a look at [`HttpSyncStart` sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/blob/master/samples/precompiled/HttpSyncStart.cs) to see how to add a custom HTTP endpoint on top of your orchestration.

Comment: Right! just found out that the function that was adding the Http trigger was another one and not the HelloSequence. My bad!